# How can I fetch search contents from different wordpress websites?

Tags: wordpress, search

I'm new to stackoverflow as a member.

Here is the issue, I have a website [https://highlifeng.com/](https://stackoverflow.com) with its sub directories https://highlifeng.com/ghana .

They are both different wordpress installations.

Now, I want that when someone search for contents on any of the sites, the results should be fetched from all the different websites.

Also, I need to be sure that it doesn't consume my sever resources.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I haven't created a code.So I'm asking how to implement this feature  on wordpress.